# For some reason my wifi and Bluetooth dont work anymore

Tags: bluetooth, adapter, wifi-direct

By that I mean I literally don't have that option in the top right menu and when I go to the settings it says wifi adapter not found and I was literally watching game of thrones on wifi and I've been using Ubuntu for more than a month never ran into a problem

Comment: Look at the system's view of the hardware: `sudo lshw`. Look at the system startup logs (as it recognizes harrdware): `sudo journalctl  -b 0`.